# SSIS incorrect datatype at Excel destination from SQL database 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, types, export-to-excel

I'm hoping someone can help me, I've explored google to death and I just can't seem to find the answer.  I'm new to using SSIS, so I don't know if this is possible...I am exporting data from SQL server database to an Excel file, which works well but it exports all numeric as string.  I then have to go in a manually convert it to numbers.  The source of the data is definitely numeric but SSIS recognises the destination cells as UNICODE STRING.  I've tried changing the format of the cells in the excel template and tried to use the import export wizard but to of no avail. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I use an Excute SQl task to crete the excel file and define the columns and datatypes. Use a connection type of EXCEL and then a create table statment to create the tab in the excel file. See example below:

```
CREATE TABLE `MyExcelFile` (
     `FIRST_NAME` NVARCHAR(100),
    `MIDDLE_NAME` NVARCHAR(50),
    `LAST_NAME` NVARCHAR(255),
    `BUSINESS_NAME` NVARCHAR(255),
    `ADDR1` NVARCHAR(200),
    `ADDR2` NVARCHAR(200),
    `ADDR3` NVARCHAR(200),
    `CITY` NVARCHAR(100),
    `STATE` NVARCHAR(50),
    `COUNTRY_CD` NVARCHAR(2),
    `ZIP` NVARCHAR(50) 
     `TOTAL_COUNT` INT,
    `TOTAL_AMOUNT` NUMERIC (10,2),
)
```

Comment: to clarify: this only works if you are using the JET OLEDB Provider (set Excel Version to **97-2003** in Connection Manager)

Does not work with any Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider I have tested (12, 16)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to get SSIS to see that you want the Excel data to be numeric.  Try this:

1. format the cells in the sheet and save.
2. edit the SSIS Excel destination
3. in the Mappings tab hover your mouse cursor over the destination column that is supposed to be numeric.  Look at the tool tip to see if it's showing a numeric data type.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I did try that but when I hovered over the mappings in SSIS it was still showing string.  I did find another way, which was to create a row below the column headers with (dummy) numeric values  (e.g. zeros).  This does trick SSIS to identify these columns as numeric and exports the data below this row in the right data types.  Probably not the best way, but works for me.